EF Core eager loading collections when GroupBy used after Include
var productsByRecalls = await _context
  .Products
  .Include(x => x.Suppliers)                              // <-----
  .Include(x => x.Recalls)                                // <-----
  .AsSplitQuery()
  .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt)
  .Where(x => x.Status == ProductStatus.Approved)
  .GroupBy(x => x.Recalls)                                // <-----
  .Where(x => x.Any()).Select(x => x.SingleOrDefault())
  .ToListAsync();

Without grouping that works as expected, and the Include collections are eager loaded.
But when using grouping, the Suppliers and Recalls collections are empty.
Why does this happen, and how can I include them?

When you call GroupBy, the result is a collection of groups, and each group is essentially a projection of the original query results. The Include statements are intended to be applied to entities directly, not to grouped projections. As a result, the eager loading configured by Include is not carried over after the GroupBy call, leading to empty collections for Suppliers and Recalls. So what you are trying achieve needs your query splitted into two part as a work around.

What is this code trying to do in the first place? Grouping by an entire table makes little sense in SQL. It looks like you're trying to pick the earliest recalled product for every Recall? In that case you should probably start from context.Recalls, use a filtered include to retrieve only approved products

.Where(x => x.Any()).Select(x => x.SingleOrDefault()) is a bit superfluous once you realize you're effectively trying to do a TOP 1 in a subquery. Even if the intention is to restrict results to products with only a single Recall, .Where(x => x.Any()) isn't needed because the HAVING COUNT(*)=1 clause won't return any NULL rows. Please explain what you want to do, post the table schema and classes so people can tell you how to solve the real problem

What does it mean, grouping by Recalls collection?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv based on the shared query Recalls is the inidividual table,  navigation property of Products table. Query result need to be group by the Recalls value.

@MdFaridUddinKiron, maybe you have better crystal ball, but I see from question that Recalls is collection navigation property.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Right you are.

Thanks to all the replies. The example is contrived, I tried to avoid a foo/bar/baz sample. I can't post the real code, but what I posted is functionally identical to my actual problem. Thanks for the explanation that an Include instruction is not respected after the Include. I will try to think of a better example, or just implement it another way.

Assuming this is EF Core it appears to be a bug, which you should file on https://github.com/dotnet/efcore


But when using grouping, the Suppliers and Recalls collections are
empty.

Using GroupBy creates groups of data based on your query. Each group acts like a snapshot of the original results. However, Include statements are meant to add related data to individual items, not groups made with GroupBy. Because of this, the extra data you wanted to load with Include (like Suppliers and Recalls) isn't included in the final results after the grouping happens, leaving them empty.

Why does this happen, and how can I include them?

Based on your scenario and description, I have tried to reproduce your issue and found that in order to implement what you are trying to achieve, you can project your query results into a DTO or an anonymous type that includes the related data before performing the grouping.
What I mean is, first load the data with the Include statements to ensure related data is eagerly loaded.
After that, once the data has been loaded, you can perform the GroupBy and other operations in-memory. This ensures that the Include statements have already taken effect before the grouping is done.
Let's have a look at the implementation.
Immagine, I have following sample data:
 var product1 = new Product
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Product1",
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
        Status = ProductStatus.Approved,
        Suppliers = new List<Supplier>
        {
            new Supplier { Id = 1, Name = "Supplier1", ProductId = 1 },
            new Supplier { Id = 2, Name = "Supplier2", ProductId = 1 }
        },
            Recalls = new List<Recall>
        {
            new Recall { Id = 1, Reason = "Reason1", ProductId = 1 },
            new Recall { Id = 2, Reason = "Reason2", ProductId = 1 }
        }
    };
    
    var product2 = new Product
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Product2",
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5),
        Status = ProductStatus.Approved,
        Suppliers = new List<Supplier>
        {
            new Supplier { Id = 3, Name = "Supplier3", ProductId = 2 }
        },
            Recalls = new List<Recall>
        {
            new Recall { Id = 3, Reason = "Reason3", ProductId = 2 }
        }
    };
    
    var product3 = new Product
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "Product3",
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
        Status = ProductStatus.Pending
    };

So first fetch approved products:
var products = new List<Product> { product1, product2, product3 };

var approvedProducts = products.Where(x => x.Status == ProductStatus.Approved)
.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt)
.ToList();

Now, based on the filtered result would perform grouping and selection:
var productsByRecalls = approvedProducts
    .GroupBy(x => x.Recalls)
    .Where(g => g.Any())
    .Select(g => g.SingleOrDefault())
    .ToList();

Finally, return the productsByRecalls.
Output:



EF Core LINQ tanslator and LINQ to Objects are different things. IMHO, this answer is useless without EF Core.

But if I am not mistaken, question been asked on EF core, and I also simulated on EF core as well.

I see only lists. How it is related to EF Core? Anyway question looks wrong. Grouping Products by collection has no sence.

Let's wait for the OP get back and see our additional questions so that OP may have exact explanation. I just tried to simulate scenario so that it might help the OP if that fits in.

I ultimately restructured my code to avoid the problem, but your answer actually explains the problem and provides a solution... so accepted. Thanks!

Thanks for your response, I am glad to assist you on this.

You are trying to retrieve the first record of each group, which can be achieved in a more SQL-native way:
Note, that I have replaced Recalls with SomeKey. It should show how to proceed with such queries in EF Core.
var products = _context.Products
    .Include(x => x.Suppliers)
    .Include(x => x.Recalls)
    .Where(x => x.Status == ProductStatus.Approved);

var query = 
  from d in products.Select(d => new { d.SomeKey }).Distinct()
  from p in products.Where(p => p.SomeKey == d.SomeKey)
    .OrderBy(p => p.CreatedAt)
    .Take(1)
  select p;

var productsByRecalls = await query
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();


Thank you this is an interesting solution.

When you use GroupBy in your query, it transforms the result into a collection of groups, which disrupts the eager loading specified by the Include statements. As a result, the Suppliers and Recalls collections are not being loaded. As a solution, you may perform the grouping operation in memory after fetching the data from the database, e.x.:
// Step 1: Fetch the data with includes
var products = await _context
    .Products
    .Include(x => x.Suppliers)
    .Include(x => x.Recalls)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt)
    .Where(x => x.Status == ProductStatus.Approved)
    .ToListAsync();

// Step 2: Perform the grouping and filtering in memory
var productsByRecalls = products
    .GroupBy(x => x.Recalls)
    .Where(g => g.Any())
    .Select(g => g.SingleOrDefault())
    .ToList();


This will only hide the problem and result in terrible performance even for very little data. The database isn't an implementation detail and typically is orders of magnitude more powerful than any client thanks to indexes, powerful CPUs, fast disks and plenty of RAM

but what do you mean by terrible performance? And why exactly it won't solve the problem?

Imagine loading 1000 products in memory just to select 10. Or 100K products. That's terrible any way you measure it. Overall time, network latency, memory usage in both the server and client, disk usage. And will also block the tables for a lot longer than needed, delaying any other query that tries to modify rows in these tables

Fair enough, but what if we try to fetch only necessary data, for example fetching only product IDs and their recall IDs, then group by recall IDs in memory and get the product IDs and only then load the products with the necessary includes based on the grouped product IDs

that should optimise our queries while working on a large sets

or, if we're talking about really huge amount of data - why are we even talking about LINQ? Why not to perform paging on the SQL side?

That's the same mistake with less data (and susceptible to ghosts, as the IDs are now loaded separately). Why load 10K rows and try to filter without any indexes when you can just load a single row with just the data you want This isn't a what if, it's a basic error in both ORMs and database querying.  In fact, what's the point of using an ORM if you don't intend to load Objects? Might as well write a clean SQL query to load just the data you want.

I ultimately restructured my query to avoid the problem, but appreciate your help, thanks.
